# count lines in array and split into 2 divs php

Tags: javascript, php, string, count, split

I have a table in my website with 4 columns. I'm using ACF custom field to enter my content.

```
 $string = get_field('projets');
```

my strings are split into two divs, date_index & texte_index... date_index display the date, and text_index displays the text, so each strings is split when finding a blank space.
like this :

here is the content I enter = 2013-07 PARIS COLLÈGE DE FRANCE
and here is how it is displayed :

```
<div class="date_index">2013-07</div><div class="texte_index">PARIS COLLÈGE DE FRANCE</div>
```

it works fine.

then my frist array is split into two column, when first column have 130 lines, then the next lines are displayed in another column.

here is my code :

```
<div class="columns_projets_1">
<p><?php 
$string = get_field('projets'); 
$array = explode("\n", $string);
for($i = 0; $i <130; $i++){
$dateAndText= explode(' ', $array[$i], 2);
echo '<div class="date_index">'.$dateAndText[0].'</div>';
echo '<div class="texte_index">'.$dateAndText[1].'</div>';
}
?></p>
</div>

<div class="columns_projets_2">
<p><?php 
$string = get_field('projets'); 
$array = explode("\n", $string);
for($i = 130; $i <count($array)-1; $i++){
$dateAndText= explode(' ', $array[$i], 2);
echo '<div class="date_index">'.$dateAndText[0].'</div>';
echo '<div class="texte_index">'.$dateAndText[1].'</div>';
}
?></p>
</div>
```

then I have a 3rd column, here is the code :

```
<div class="columns_conferences">
<p><?php 
$string = get_field('conferences'); 
$array = explode("\n", $string);
for($i = 0; $i <300; $i++){
$dateAndText= explode(' ', $array[$i], 2);
echo '<div class="date_index">'.$dateAndText[0].'</div>';
echo '<div class="texte_index">'.$dateAndText[1].'</div>';
}
?></p>
</div>
```

and my 4th column :

```
<div class="columns_monographies">
<p><?php 
$string = get_field('monographies'); 
$array = explode("\n", $string);
for($i = 0; $i <300; $i++){
$dateAndText= explode(' ', $array[$i], 2);
echo '<div class="date_index">'.$dateAndText[0].'</div>';
echo '<div class="texte_index">'.$dateAndText[1].'</div>';
}
?></p>
</div>
```

first of all I would like to delete the condition ( $i <300 )on the 3rd and 4th column, I don't want to have limits in this two columns, but when I try to delete the condition nothing is displayed...

secondly I would like to count the lines in the 3rd column, and this number will be the limit of my first column. so my 1st and 3rd column will have the same lines number.

do you understand what I mean ?
it should be something like that but I can't manage to make it work :

in my 1st column :

for($i = 0; $i <130; $i++){

instead of 130, the number of lines of my 3rd column array.

and for 2nd column ;

for($i = 130; $i

instead of 130, the number of lines of my 3rd column array.

I really hope you can help me with this,

here is a github link :

https://gist.github.com/mattieumoreau/7431037

thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 0):

To fix your first issue, use sizeof(array) rather than a specific number, e.g.:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
    $dateAndText= explode(' ', $array[$i], 2);
    echo '<div class="date_index">'.$dateAndText[0].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="texte_index">'.$dateAndText[1].'</div>';
}
```

Edit:
Your third column would look a bit like this:

```
<div class="columns_conferences">
    <p><?php
        $string = get_field('conferences');
        $array = explode("\n", $string);
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
            $dateAndText= explode(' ', $array[$i], 2);
            echo '<div class="date_index">'.$dateAndText[0].'</div>';
            echo '<div class="texte_index">'.$dateAndText[1].'</div>';
        }
        ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: ok thanks sherwood but how can I define that I need the sizeof array from the 3rd column ?

Comment: ok thanks @sherwoor but how can I define that I need the sizeof array from the 3rd column ?

Comment: I have amended the answer above with how your third column should look.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues going on here.

1. If you delete the condition, either your for loop is erroring out or it's going on forever (depends on how you're trying to delete it). To get all the records, you want `for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i += 1) { ...`
2. To limit the length of the first column of 'projets' to the length of 'conferences', you'll need to pick up the data ahead of time, then display it. Here's what I mean:

   ```
   $projets = explode("\n", get_field('projets'));
   $conferences = explode("\n", get_field('conferences'));
   $monographies = explode("\n", get_field('monographies'));

   // Now we want to limit the length of the first column of projets (col 1) to the
   // length of conferences (col 3).
   $projets = array_chunk($projets, count($conferences)); // Split the projets into a set of arrays of the right length.
   $projets1 = array_shift($projets); // Grab the first one... that's the data for the first column.
   $projets2 = array_reduce($projets, 'array_merge', array()); // Merge the remaining arrays into a single array for display.
   ```

   and then :

   ```
   function displayDateAndText ($obj)
   {
       $dateAndText = explode(' ', $obj, 2);
       echo "<div class=\"date_index\">{$dateAndText[0]}</div>";
       echo "<div class=\"texte_index\">{$dateAndText[1]}</div>";
   }
   function displayRecords ($records)
   {
       echo '<p>';
       $limit = count($records);
       for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i += 1)
       {
           displayDateAndText($records[$i]);
       }
       echo '</p>';
   }
   ?>
   <div class="columns_projets_1">
       <?php
          displayRecords($projets1);
       ?>
   </div>
   <div class="columns_projets_2">
       <?php
          displayRecords($projets2);
       ?>
   </div>
   <div class="conferences">
       <?php
          displayRecords($conferences);
       ?>
   </div>
   <div class="monographies">
       <?php
           displayRecords($monographies);
       ?>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: thanks @jameslafferty, I corrected my the count($array) in my 3rd and 4th column, that's perfect. but I don't understand how I can limit the number of lines for my first column and my second, can you explain please ?

Comment: Just added logic to show how to get the $largestCount. You may need to make some additional changes to your code to get it to work, but hopefully that conveys the idea.

Comment: I think maybe I'd misread your question a little bit before. Just updated the code to give a fuller answer.

Comment: thanks @jameslafferty, I'm trying to understand your answer but it seems like chinese for me ;-)...
can you please tell me where to add this code ? maybe github if you won't mind ?

Comment: Here's a fork of your gist: https://gist.github.com/jameslafferty/7434986 Please do note that I haven't tested to code.

Comment: in fact I just need to count the number of lines of my column 3, and this will be the limit of lines of my column 1, after the limit is reached, than colum 2 starts. do you see what I mean ?

Comment: @user2882154 Just updated the gist. I'll update the code in my answer in a moment. I think I probably lost track of your requirements a little bit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41046/discussion-between-jameslafferty-and-user2882154)